# Can I set a default program for a certain file type without also making it visible in the dash (Activities overview)?

Tags: gnome-shell, default-programs, activities-overview

I have a script which I want to use as the default app to open certain files. But, when I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open the dash or the '*Activities*' overview and type stuff in to search for applications, I *don't* want to see this script.

The only way I'm aware of to set a default app is to right click the file and click *Open with other application > View all applications*, but that seems to only list the applications in `~/.local/share/applications`, which also appear in the dash.

Can these two behaviors be decoupled?

Comment: without also making it visible in the dash.. as you mentioned this in question.. for example you want to open a mp3 file with `rhythmbox`.. this app is visible in dash... so you dont want to see `rhythmbox` in dash but still be able to open.. this is possible.. but is it what you are looking for??

Comment: @PRATAP Yes. Because the program is actually a small python script that I wrote, and it doesn't make sense to launch it "on its own", with no input file. So it doesn't make sense to show it in the dash. I just want to be able to double click on certain files and have them be opened by the script.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. First create a simple `.desktop` launcher file for the programme in `~/.local/share/applications/`, say `appname.desktop` and add the following lines to it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Name of the programme
Comment=A short description
Exec=/full/path/to/the/script %U
Type=Application
Icon=/full/path/to/icon-image
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=true
```

Then save file. After that you would find this application in '*Open with other application*' > '*View all applications*' and would be able to set it as the default programme.

The `NoDisplay=true` line hides the application from '*Activities*' overview.

> `NoDisplay` means "this application exists, but don't display it in the menus". This can be useful to e.g. associate this application with MIME types, so that it gets launched from a file manager (or other apps), without having a menu entry for it (there are tons of good reasons for this, including e.g. the `netscape -remote`, or `kfmclient openURL` kind of stuff).
>   ([source](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys))